# Accumulo - MiniAccumuloCluster Connection Refused

Tags: java, connection, development-environment, accumulo

I'm using the MiniAccumuloCluster (MAC) 1.5 jar and attempting to even just instantiate a MAC object but can't seem to connect to it. I get a ton of errors akin to the following:

```
13/07/08 14:31:29 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:14060
13/07/08 14:31:29 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:692)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
```

And ending with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to zookeeper (localhost:14060) within 2x zookeeper timeout period 30000
at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooSession.connect(ZooSession.java:96)
at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooSession.getSession(ZooSession.java:146)
at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooReader.getSession(ZooReader.java:36)
at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooReader.getZooKeeper(ZooReader.java:40)
at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooCache.getZooKeeper(ZooCache.java:56)
at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooCache.retry(ZooCache.java:127)
at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooCache.get(ZooCache.java:233)
at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooCache.get(ZooCache.java:188)
at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.ZooKeeperInstance.getInstanceID(ZooKeeperInstance.java:143)
at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.ZooKeeperInstance.<init>(ZooKeeperInstance.java:104)
at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.ZooKeeperInstance.<init>(ZooKeeperInstance.java:85)
at Accumulo.Accumulo.connectToMiniCluster(Accumulo.java:454)
at Accumulo.Accumulo.<init>(Accumulo.java:140)
at Accumulo.FrontEnd.main(FrontEnd.java:56)
```

Accumulo.Accumulo.connectoToMiniCluster (line 454) is:

```
Instance inst = new ZooKeeperInstance(mac.getInstanceName(), mac.getZooKeepers());
```

Any suggestions? The Internet is wildly lacking documentation for a lot of the Accumulo framework, including MAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was missing a handful of JAR libraries and I discerned this by looking through the JUnit TemporaryFolder log files. After downloading all the appropriate libraries I resolved my issue.

Download all the dependency jars to get any java code that works with accumulo from here:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.accumulo/accumulo-core/1.5.0
and that should fix be a good starting point for addressing accumulo java code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you start your MiniAccumuloCluster instance before attempting to instantiate the ZooKeeperInstance?

Make sure you call mac.start().

Comment: I did not call start() before creating my Instance, but after.

Comment: If you say adding in jars fixed your issue, so be it. However, given your stacktrace, you were blocked in the constructor of ZooKeeperInstance because you didn't start your MiniAccumuloCluster instance.

Comment: I figured out that my Junit3 rules weren't quite right and so the temporary folder wasn't being created to make a File object for the MiniAccumuloCluster object instantiation.